# Selenium WebDriver Unable to locate element in link

Tags: jakarta-ee, selenium-webdriver

I have [web page](https://testvfgroup.appdirect.com/home) and I wanted to automate this page but when I clicking "Log In" button, it is prompting me an error:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Log In"}

Please suggest where am I wrong here?

**project.java**

```
package com.saas.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import com.saas.test.Configuration_file;

public class Test_1 extends Configuration_file {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration_file var = new Configuration_file();

        WebDriver firefox_dri = new FirefoxDriver();

        firefox_dri.get("https://testvfgroup.appdirect.com/home");
        firefox_dri.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
        //firefox_dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.adb-primary_nav--link")).click();


        //firefox_dri.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Up")).click();  
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using explicit wait. It would speed up the execution.

```
WebDriver firefox_dri = new FirefoxDriver();
wait = new WebDriverWait(firefox_dri , 120);
        firefox_dri.get("https://testvfgroup.appdirect.com/home");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Log In")));
        firefox_dri.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
        firefox_dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.adb-primary_nav--link")).click();


        firefox_dri.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Up")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code. Only, you are trying to locate an element even before it's page is loaded entirely. Try to give some [implicitlyWait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) between `get` & `find` calls.

```
WebDriver firefox_dri = new FirefoxDriver();

firefox_dri.get("https://testvfgroup.appdirect.com/home");
firefox_dri.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
firefox_dri.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
```